# What is the cause of the minor mass difference between the proton and the neutron?

Tags: standard-model, quarks, neutrons, protons, isospin-symmetry

As known, the proton is from two up and a single down quark, while the neutron is from a single up and two down quarks. The down quark is a little bit more massive and the up, and so the neutron is also a little bit more massive as the proton. It was my naive layman's hypothese.

But the masses of the quarks (4 and 8 MeV) take only a tiny part in the whole mass of the baryons ($\approx 1\textrm{ GeV}$). Their masses are coming mainly from the gluon field around them.

And, considering the relative recent [charming result](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2008/nov/21/proton-and-neutron-masses-calculated-from-first-principles) of the calculation of the protons and neutrons from the principles, I think maybe this question could have a more detailed answer.

I think the mass difference is coming from the difference of the gluon field, is it okay? *What* is that difference?

---

*Extension:* [comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/85/whats-with-the-very-slightly-larger-mass-of-the-neutron-compared-to-the-proton#comment3237_1519) says, that calculation couldn't yet differentiate between protons and neutrons. I hope, maybe the last 8 years made possible this improvement.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/85/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Only related, but not duplicate. This question asks for the difference of the gluon fields, the other doesn't (and the answers miss this info).

Comment: [Borsanyi et al 2015](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/347/6229/1452.full.pdf).

Comment: arxiv version  https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4088