# Why protons are stable but Neutrons not?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, standard-model, quarks, neutrons, protons

just read something about standard model and find it very interesting, proton is made of there subatomic particle  U,U,D and neutron have U,D,D .
electromagnetic force between U,U,D wants to rip apart it but strong force make it stable .

when  compare it with proton in neutron electromagnetic force is less and strong force also there between U,D,D . 
but why neutron is not stable and a single free neutron  will decay  in less than 15 min ?

it must be vice versa !

so why proton is stable but neutron is not?

Comment: [Whether the proton is stable or not is actually still an open question.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay#Baryogenesis)

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/85/whats-with-the-very-slightly-larger-mass-of-the-neutron-compared-to-the-proton) : free neutrons are heavier than protons, so they decay to them. As to [why](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/347/6229/1452)...

Answer (score 4):

Masses: $m_n-m_p\approx 1.5$ MeV, so the neutron β-decays to a proton, by emission of an electron (0.5 MeV) and a practically massless antineutrino.
But the proton has nothing to decay to, at least in established, non-speculative physics. (So no GUT theorizing here.)

Why? You already appreciated that EM works against this. But $m_d -m_u\approx  2.5$ MeV. Why? nobody knows *that*.

The competition between QED (your guess) and QCD (the strong interactions: dispositive!) is sorted out in [Borsanyi et al 2015](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/347/6229/1452) in lattice gauge theory:

> The existence and stability of atoms rely on the fact that neutrons are more
>   massive than protons. The measured mass difference is only 0.14% of the average
>   of the two masses. A slightly smaller or larger value would have led to a dramatically different universe. Here, we show that this difference results from the competition between electromagnetic and mass isospin breaking effects. We performed lattice quantum-chromodynamics and quantum-electrodynamics computations with four nondegenerate Wilson fermion flavors and computed the neutron-proton mass-splitting with an accuracy of 300 kilo–electron volts, which is greater than 0 by 5 standard deviations. ...

They get it right on the nose:
$$
m_n-m_p  = 1.51(16)(23)~ MeV, \\    \Delta_{QCD}= 2.52(17)(24) ~ MeV,     \\ \Delta_{QED}= –1.00(07)(14) ~MeV .     
$$